# How to yank string before a special character?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Example line: `^    some_string    : other_string $`.

How to yank `some_string` before `:` without the spaces|tabs?

Comment: With your cursor on the first character of the line (i.e. the first `s` in `some_string`) you want to do `yf:` to yank until `:`?

Comment: Cursor can be any place in the current line. Tried yf:, it will also yank the spaces between the string and `:`.  Seems yiw can do the job.

Comment: Oh I didn't understand what you meant. Yes definitely `yiw` is what you are looking for you can see more text objects there [`:h object-select`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#object-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably know all commands are quite location dependent.
So the *best* command will differ depending on your starting location.

`yiw` will work fine if you are standing on the `some_string`.
If you are on the line you can get there by `^` (go to beginning first word of the line)
Then `yiw` to yank the word only. (thanks @statox)

Comment: Welcome to our site @jaan! If I may add my two cents: `0w` can be replaced by `^` ([`:h ^`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#%5e)). Also `yiw` will yank the current word while `yw` will yank the current word and the whitespaces until the next character which is OP was asking not to do :)

Comment: Thank you.
and you are very correct! i guess I was a little quick on the trigger. Should have tested before posting. I thought `^` and `0` did the same thing, good to know. And here i thought I had a pretty good understanding of vim!

Comment: That's the amazing part about Vim: you never know it all ;) You can edit your answer with the "edit" button to remove the part about `yw` to avoid confusion for future users.